# Debugging issue in the console

Tags: python

So as I want to use the debuging in my code python django in the vscode. There the server is also loaded in the debug terminal and the main issue is when the server is loaded and click on the button it should hit to the breakpoint that I place in the views.py which is not hitting at the breakpoint that I placed.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [  
        {
            "name": "Stock_manage",
            "python": "/Users/akchhabhyashakya/Desktop/python/New stock/Stock_manage/my-venv/bin/python3",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "/Users/akchhabhyashakya/Desktop/python/New stock/Stock_manage/manage.py",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload"
            ],
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "justMyCode": true,
           
            "django": true
        }
    ]
}
```

this is my launch.json and my expectation was when i click the button in the server it should hit the breakpoint that I placed in the code